# In theory, is it possible for Azure AD or B2C to leverage the Facebook SDK for auth?

Tags: facebook, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an iOS application, and my customers my be logged into Facebook via

1. The Web Browser
2. The native config in Settings
3. The Facebook app/ messenger

When I follow the instructions using MSAL or ADAL it seems that I'm only using the Safari browser for authentication.

- Is there any way (even in theory) to leverage the credentials already stored within option 2 or option 3?
- What would be needed for the MSAL / ADAL to leverage option 2 or 3?

Answer (score 4):

The ADAL ObjC v3 experimental library is currently not supported and we recommend using a 3rd party library. Our current recommendation is [NXOAuth2](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client). There is no MSAL for iOS yet. If I were to take a guess #2 might not work due to a need to show user consent interrupts, and #3 would add a dependency on the Facebook SDK that we would not want to require all users to take. You can file a feature request for both of those, but neither would be coming for a while, assuming they are even feasible.

Edit: #1 will be possible in the future using `SFSafariViewController`, but B2C currently doesn't support the features necessary to securely use `SFSafariViewController` in app.

Comment: What are the features of B2C that's needed for secure iOS usage? I am asking to understand and compare to AAD and other providers

Comment: Prior B2C was lacking support for PKCE (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636) however that is in place now. A preview of MSAL for iOS, using SFSafariViewController, will be officially debute later this week during BUILD, however is currently available on GitHub (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc), albeit without a release in Master, which will be coming shortly.